# Female Participation in Judicial Systems

Tags: judiciary

I was browsing the list of Chief Justices of the apex court of India and found that none of them have been female. Moreover, there are only 4 sitting female judges in the Supreme Court out of the total 33 judges.

While India has had female presidents, a female PM and multiple female union ministers and state CMs, overall, the participation of women in judiciary seems quite low.

Even [in the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_Kingdom#Current_judges), the participation seems quite low.

Am I correct in my analysis? **How does this compare with female participation in judiciary of other countries?**

If the analysis is indeed correct that the participation of women in judiciary is much less than other fields like the executive and the work force in general (**in the world**), I'd like to ask why is that the case? What factors separate the inclusivity in the judiciary from inclusivity in general?

Comment: I want to point out that the original statement is a bit confusing. If women account for about 10% of justices, then if chief justices were selected at random, then it's unlikely you'll get any as women until 10 changes on average. Obviously, the chief justices are not selected at random. A quick look suggests that there were 50 chief justices in India and during many of those years, I imagine, women were not in the courts so obviously there could not be a women chief justice that year.

Comment: @uberhaxed You are correct, and indeed India is supposed to have the first female CJI in 2027 - but the question is basically about lack of female participation in the judiciary, overall, rather than just the CJI for which you rightly pointed out the reason.

Comment: I'm slightly shcoked to learn India has 33 Justices on their Supreme Court. That is a stunningly large number.

Comment: @QuantumWalnut Considering the population of India, it is appropriate. In fact, the SC (judiciary overall) is severely *understaffed* at the moment.

Comment: @whoisit The number of Justices certainly should reflect the population, but at a certain point the size could make consensus too hard to reach. I think once their number surpasses 20, the number of Justices start to matter less and their diversity start to matter more; such as their gender, language, regional upbringing, etc. For instance, you can have 33 Justices but if they're all men from Mumbai that wouldn't necessarily be very representative of the population either.

Comment: @QuantumWalnut You're right about the diversity. However, each case is taken by a few number of judges only - and only those 2-3 people have to reach consensus so that's rarely an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three separate questions posed here. I will focus on the first part, which is about comparing India to other countries in terms of female representation on its Supreme court. I will not compare this to other branches of governance, nor will I try to answer the question of explaining why the gender balance is the way it is.

The short answer is that while I did not find a global dataset to confirm this directly, **the rate of about 12% female representation (4/33) on India's Supreme Court is very likely to be well below the global average**. The average may be double this, and individual countries with over 50% women on their supreme courts are not rare.

[Here](https://www.oecd.org/gender/data/women-in-the-judiciary-working-towards-a-legal-system-reflective-of-society.htm) is a 2014 dataset for OECD countries which shows that women "hold 33.6% of judgeships in Supreme Courts." Only 4 of the countries in this group were below 20%. The lowest of these was Spain, which [as of 2020](https://sci-hub.se/10.1080/09695958.2020.1775601) has increased slightly to 17% (2/12 judges on the Spanish Constitutional Court). The top five countries are around 50%-60%. Thus **by OECD standards of gender representation on supreme courts, India would be at the very bottom**.

[image: OECD - female share of judges]

[Here](https://oig.cepal.org/en/indicators/judicial-power-percentage-women-judges-highest-court-or-supreme-court) is a different dataset of 30 countries from 2021, which also includes Spain but primarily focuses on Latin America and the Caribbean. **The Latin American average is around 30%**, and 27 of these 30 countries have ratios higher than India's 12%.

[image: Latin America, The Caribbean and The Iberian Peninsula (30 countries): Women judges in the highest court, latest available data (Percentages)]

I believe this data is sufficient to raise doubts about the speculations in the question. The Indian case is not necessarily typical by any means. A point worth emphasis is that **both in Europe and in the Caribbean, there are multiple countries where the majority of supreme court judges are women**.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer even though it doesn't fully answer the question - why is representation of women low in indian judiciary and contradictory to the fact that women in other indian political institutions have managed to reach the top?

Comment: @sfxedit I answered the question in bold. What you're raising here is a good question but I think it's a rather separate one.

Comment: Your answer is excellent. And you have indeed mentioned that you are only partly answering the question.

Answer (score 5):

In well-functioning democracies, the judiciary tend to move slower than contemporary politics in terms of gender representation.

The reasons for this are:

- Judges tend to serve for life, and people are living longer, so even if there are a lot of female judges waiting in the wings, they still need the incumbent judges on the higher level to... um, leave by natural attrition.
- The appointment process for judges are slow, sometimes necessarily to insulate them from political institutions. If a certain judge is promoted to the top at lightning speed, one might guess there is political element involved and that would harm the judiciary's credibility. So it's always a tradeoff.
- Women might be discouraged from pursuing judicial offices due to lack of representation. Many female Justices remain trailblazers of their generation because they would have to start very early to end up where they are today. That is to say it takes time to create a virtuous circle of diverse recruitment.

I would gently push back on the idea that there is a lack of female participation in judiciary. I think there are a lot of aspiring female judges today, it just takes a lot longer for them (and all judges for that matter) to get promoted because judicial systems generally move at a glacial pace.

To my knowledge, most Supreme Courts are still male-centric, though New Zealand is a notable exception where the Supreme Court has gender parity (3 female, 3 male).

Comment: (+1) The [Supreme Court of California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_Court_of_California) (a US state and *not* a country, obviously, but larger than many countries) comprises seven justices, of which at present four (including the chief justice) are female. It therefore seems that political will -- as it applies to judicial appointments -- has much to do with the composition of courts. It should be noted though that justices of the Supreme Court of California are confirmed for renewable terms and not for life, so the first bullet here certainly has some bearing on SCOTUS, for example.

Comment: Good answer. Note though that in India, judges have a retirement age and don't serve for life. Moreover, the indian judiciary is unique in that it has greatly reduced the role of the executive (politicians) in deciding who can be a judge.